# Using boost strings algorithms with iterators

Tags: c++, string, boost

I have a string defined with 2 iterators. I want to check, if it ends with some string.
Now my code looks like

```
algorithm::ends_with(string(begin,end),"format(");
```

Is there some way to execute this function without constructing a string? Something like

```
algorithm::ends_with(begin,end,"format(");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
 std::string s = "something";
 bool b = boost::algorithm::ends_with( &s[0], "g");  // true
```

Iterator can be used to construct a range as well:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>

std::string s = "somet0hing";
std::string::iterator it = s.begin();
bool b = boost::algorithm::ends_with( 
                        boost::make_iterator_range( it, s.end()), "g");  // true
```

or:

```
std::string s = "somet0hing";
std::string::iterator it = s.begin();
bool b = boost::algorithm::ends_with( &(*it), "g");  // true
```

Comment: Isn't that using a 0-terminated string instead of a range? So embedded zeroes are handled differently... Often appropriate anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator added version using make_itearator_range